# How to populate param. value for the http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ javascript correctly?

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

How to populate param. value for the http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ javascript correctly?

I want to pass some image title by

```
 params: { 
     param1: imgTitle
 },
```

Where `$("#ImageTitle").val();` refers to `<input type="text" id="ImageTitle" name="ImageTitle" value="" />`

Any help please!

Thank you!!!

[image]

**UPDATES**:

The final solution is here.

```
<script type="text/jscript">

                                var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                                    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader-demo1'),
                                    allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif'],
                                    sizeLimit: 2147483647, // max size
                                    action: '/TradeshowSpeakers/UploadFile',
                                    multiple: false,
                                    onSubmit: function (id, filename) {
                                        this.params.param1 = $("#ImageTitle").val();
                                    },
                                    onProgress: function (id, fileName, loaded, total) {
                                    },
                                    onComplete: function (id, fileName, responseJSON) {
                                        //alert(responseJSON[0].Image);
                                    }
                                });
```

Comment: `obj.property = 'foo';` also see [this](http://www.kirupa.com/html5/variable_scope_js.htm)

Comment: Sorry? How it should be then?

Comment: hmm I think something you'd replace `var imgTitle` with `this.params.param1 = $('#imageTitle').val();` and change `param1: imgTitle` to `param1: ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imgTitle ...
```

having been declared in a function is not in scope (visible to) the assignment of `param1` and so it should be replaced with

```
this.params.param1 = $('#imageTitle').val();
```

Also as teh assignment of `param1: imgTitle` is now irrelevant it can just be assigned an empty string or false etc.

A couple of references in understanding whats going on here:

- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/fully-understanding-the-this-keyword/
- http://www.kirupa.com/html5/variable_scope_js.htm